# how to replace the ingress nginx-controller default "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" with my own custom nginx.conf file?

Tags: nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I want to deploy an ingress nginx controller in my cluster. I currently have an nginx service(type LB) running in my cluster using a custom nginx.conf to route the traffic inside the k8s cluster.
I want to replace the nginx service with an ingress nginx controller.
When I deployed the nginx controller, I realized it did not pick up the nginx.conf file that I have in the configmap.

I wondered if there is a way to override the controller default nginx.conf with mine.

or how can attach my config file to the ingress controller and have it use the new nginx.conf instead of the default one to route the traffic.

Thank you

I deployed the ingress controller using https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/deploy/static/provider/cloud

but it does not use the the customized nginx.conf file to route the traffic inside the cluster.